# Bootstrap Slider giving erratic decimal values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Bootstrap Slider from: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

It works great but is giving me decimal values that are correct but as I slide it it goes from 2.00 to .2.0000000000001 then the next value is 2.01 and so on.

How can I limit the decimal value to .00 (i.e. only 2 places)?

```
<input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal" id="weight" name="weight" data-slider-min="0.24" data-slider-max="16.38" data-slider-step="0.01" data-slider-value="[0.24,16.38]" value="0.24,16.38" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show" data-slider-handle="square">

$(function(){
$('#weight').slider({
      formater: function(value) {
        return ''+value;
      }
}).on('slideStop', function(ev){
 $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
});

$("#getVal").click(function() {
      console.log("Value 2 = "+$("#weight").data('slider').getValue());
});
});
```